# npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE errno 1

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I am not able to build my project after cloning from github on gitbash.I have tried building code with node v0.12 and v9.2 also but no luck.The version I am currently using :

node v8.9.1

npm 5.5.1

As soon as I run command 'npm run build',I get this error :

```js
> print-web@0.1.54 build C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\djFinal\djc-app\print-web
> webpack --progress

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! print-web@0.1.54 build: `webpack --progress`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the print-web@0.1.54 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log     ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-11-23T05     _58_00_915Z-debug.log
```

The error log:

```js
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~prebuild: print-web@0.1.54
6 info lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: print-web@0.1.54
7 verbose lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\djFinal\djc-app\print-web\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\MKS Toolkit\mksnt;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\jre\bin\classic;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\lib\cpp;C:\IBM\InformationServer\ASBNode\apps\proxy\cpp\vc60\MT_dll\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Enterprise Vault\EVClient";C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: CWD: C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\djFinal\djc-app\print-web
10 silly lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'webpack --progress' ]
11 silly lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle print-web@0.1.54~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: print-web@0.1.54 build: `webpack --progress`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:280:16)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
14 verbose pkgid print-web@0.1.54
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\RaghuvanshiD\djFinal\djc-app\print-web
16 verbose Windows_NT 6.1.7601
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v8.9.1
19 verbose npm  v5.5.1
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error print-web@0.1.54 build: `webpack --progress`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the print-web@0.1.54 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: > 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Looks like `node` is not correctly installed.

Comment: I have installed it from official website and tried deleting and reinstalling also.Still the same error.

Comment: do me a favour, open cmd.exe and type `node` and enter. let me know what it says

Comment: anyway, if it gives the same error, please ensure you set the path to nodejs in your environment variable.

Comment: I had set path in environment variable to node js and i confirmed it.

Comment: In cmd.exe,it is giving this error:  'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.